# Filtrar filas solo del body de una tabla html con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla que representa las reservas, el detalle es cuando busco la(s) habitacion(es), el filtro no respeta a los `<th>`. 
Cómo haría para que el filtro solo coja a las filas del `body` de la tabla en el `javascript`.

```js
            function doSearch() {
                var tableReg = document.getElementById('regTable');
                var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase();
                for (var i = 1; i < tableReg.rows.length; i++) {
                    var cellsOfRow = tableReg.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                    var found = false;
                    for (var j = 0; j < cellsOfRow.length && !found; j++) {
                        var compareWith = cellsOfRow[j].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                        if (searchText.length == 0 || (compareWith.indexOf(searchText) > -1)) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        tableReg.rows[i].style.display = '';
                    } else {
                        tableReg.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
```

```css
.reserva {
background-color: #f66a6a;
color: #f66a6a
}
```

```html
<input id="searchTerm" onkeyup="doSearch()" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar habitacion" type="text" >
<table border="1" id="regTable" >
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="text-center" colspan="20">
     Reservas - Enero 2019 del 1-10 
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>habitacion</th>           
   <th>1</th>
   <th colspan="2">2</th>
   <th colspan="2">3</th>
   <th colspan="2">4</th>
   <th colspan="2">5</th>
   <th colspan="2">6</th>
   <th colspan="2">7</th>
   <th colspan="2">8</th>
   <th colspan="2">9</th>
   <th colspan="2">10</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>101-simple</td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="6"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="4"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="3"></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>102-simple</td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="4" class="reserva"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="4"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>   
   <td></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>103-doble</td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="4"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="6"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>  
      <td></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>104-Triple</td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="4"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td> 
   <td></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>101-Matrimonial</td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="4"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td> 
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td class="reserva" colspan="5"></td>             
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No me fije en el `for` de la function javascript, como había agregado otra fila de `th` al inicio de la tabla y de la misma manera el contador tenia que empezar en 2  `var i=2`
mejor dicho cambiamos la 4ta linea de código del javascript por:
`for (var i = 2; i < tableReg.rows.length; i++) {`

Comment: Si la has resuelto, por favor, aprueba tu propia respuesta